# How to connect to mysql db in eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, server

To connect MySQL, I added the mysql-connector jar to the classpath of the program. But when I tried to run and add the server database I'm having the following error:

> sql exception: server shows more than one timezone, do specific
>   timezone to utilize the server using server timezone configuration.

To remove this error and to use the MySQL server what should i do???

Answer (score 0):

You are facing JDBC Timezone issues.
Add following parametre in your DB Connection URL to solve Timezone
related issues.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```